# Understanding unexpected Jinja2 control structure iteration

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

New to Jinja2 and trying to understand why the following block is working as expected:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
<!-- http://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/zbKAD/ --!>
{% block title %}Video Feed{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    <h1>Video Feed</h1>
    <p>This page can only be viewed by logged in users.</p>
    <p>You are logged in as <b>{{ current_user.username }}</b>.</p>

    <!--here we will loop through video feed returned after user-submitted tag interpolation with OVP API feed has been processed by video feed processing logic elsewhere in app --!>

{% for dict in video_package %}

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

 <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
<div style="display:none">

</div>

<!--
 By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C
 found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/.
 -->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="width" value="480" />
    <param name="height" value="270" />
    <param name="playerID" value="42392001" />
    <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAABvaL8JE~,ufBHq_IZRv9kTOlTe" />
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="isUI" value="true" />
    <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value="{{ dict["videoID"] }}" />

</object>

<!--
 This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
 as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
 the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
 -->
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>

<!-- End of Brightcove Player -->

</div>

     <!-- Button trigger modal -->
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
       Get Asset Data
     </button>

       <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               Description: {{ dict["description"] }}
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

     <p>
     </p>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

The for loop `{% for dict in video_package %}` is iterating through a list of dictionaries that each contain a few key/value pairs such as `videoID`, `description`, etc.

Here's an example of what video_package might look like:

```
[{'description': u"King Lawal believes with Davis", 'name': u"Muhammed fights smart", 'videoID': u'48257001'}, {'description': u'Kyra twister event', 'name': u'wins by a ground', 'videoID': u'4870086579001'}, {'description': u'The Comeback', 'name': u'April 29', 'videoID': u'4869818001'}]
```

For every dict the `@videoPlayer` parameter in the video player embed code is receiving a `videoID` from `dict["videoID"]`:

```
<param name="@videoPlayer" value="{{ dict["videoID"] }}" />
```

So the template renders multiple video player embeds (as many player embeds as there are dictionaries in the list `video_package`), each with separate video IDs and works as expected.

But I'm also trying to send the text contained in `dict["description"]` to each instance of the button via:

```
<div class="modal-body">
Description: {{ dict["description"] }}
</div>
```

However, what's getting rendered in the template for each button is only the `dict["description"]` string from the first dictionary in the video_package list. In other words, each button contains the same text, which always belongs to the first dictionary even though each player is getting videoIDs from each of the dictionaries.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but given that everything is in between `{% for dict in video_package %}` and `{% endfor %}` I would have thought that each iteration through, `dict["description"]` would have a different value just as `dict["videoID"]` has a different value.

Comment: Are you sure the description values of each dictionary are different?

Comment: Yes, because when I try `{{ dict["description"] }}` right underneath `{% for dict in video_package %} ` the template renders with different descriptions (the number of descriptions depending upon the number of dicts in the list object `video_package` obviously)

Comment: You're defining `<object id="myExperience">` inside the for loop. HTML ids must be unique.

Comment: Can you (a) reduce the template to the minimum required to reproduce the problem?  And then can you (b) show us the contents of the `dict` variable just before you call the template?  Also, it's generally a bad idea to call anything in Python `dict`.  I don't think that's your problem here, but it's really easy to mess yourself up because you've masked the built-in `dict` type.

Comment: I'm sure the template is correct. Can you write a minimal example to understand what you're doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an HTML `id` as your `data-target` attribute (`data-target="#myModal"`) for the modal.  The ID attribute *must* be unique across the entire document - the normal (but not specified) browser behavior is to return the *first* DOM node with an ID when asked for one.

The fix is to update your `data-target` and your `modal`'s ID with the [current loop index](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) - e. g. `data-target="#myModal-{{loop.index}}"` and `div class="modal fade" id="myModal-{{loop.index}}"`  (you should also do the same for your `aria-labelledby` attribute and `.modal-title` ID).